# how to use put as a router call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, put

In my project I'm trying to edit readings in MySQL database using PUT and I think i have to pass 2 arguments but i get an error that says CANNOT GET /readings/1/1 what am i doing wrong?, here is my code...

```
router.put('/edit/:user_id/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {
    sugarB = req.body.sugarB,
    carbsB = req.body.carbsB,
    insulinB = req.body.insulinB,
    insulinSB = req.body.insulinSB,
    insulinFB = req.body.insulinFB,
    sugarL = req.body.sugarL,
    carbsL = req.body.carbsL,
    insulinL = req.body.insulinL,
    hbp = req.body.hbp,
    lbp = req.body.lbp,
    hr = req.body.hr,
    sugarD = req.body.sugarD,
    carbsD = req.body.carbsD,
    insulinD = req.body.insulinD
  } = req.query;

  connection.query(
    UPDATE_READINGS_QUERY, + ' WHERE user_id=?,id=?',
    [req.params.user_id], [req.params.id],
    [
      sugarB,
      carbsB,
      insulinB,
      insulinSB,
      insulinFB,
      sugarL,
      carbsL,
      insulinL,
      hbp,
      lbp,
      hr,
      sugarD,
      carbsD,
      insulinD
    ],
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err.message);
      } else {
        res.send('Rows affected: ', results.affetedRows);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: from the error you are having `CANNOT GET /readings/1/1` its seems you are doing GET request to your route. you should use a utility to make you requests like curl https://mkyong.com/web/curl-put-request-examples/, or postman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEt4bfSCuIs

Comment: Wrong request method to wrong route, seems like chance to success not to high :)

Comment: Does my code look right, what would the right request method be?